# What is "woodlump"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 'We came across a man up at Brightling who was beating his wife with
>   a bat in the garden. I was just going to **toss the man over his own
>   woodlump** when the Boy jumped the hedge and ran at him. Of course the
>   woman took her husband's part, and while the man beat him, the woman
>   scratted his face.

This is from "[Rewards and Fairies](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Rewards_and_Fairies/Cold_Iron_(story))"  by Kipling

I do not understand what "woodlump" means.

Comment: Kipling also uses it in '[A Smuggler's Song](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Smuggler%27s_Song)' - I believe it is a [woodpile](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/woodpile?searchDictCode=all).

Answer (score 3):

Well let's see...

> It's small enough to throw someone on
>   It's big enough to hide small barrels behind
>   It's can occur in a garden
>   It's something you can run around
>   And it's probably made out of "wood"

I imagine something like so

[image: here]
The word also seems to be of BrE origin

Comment: It's a strange word, because it seems to be extremely rare outside of Kipling's writing, but your conclusion does seem to be the only reasonable one.  In fact, [here's The Kipling Journal defining "woodlump" as "a woodpile"](https://books.google.com/books?id=gWQ-AQAAIAAJ&q=woodlump&dq=woodlump&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9k_vqz8DMAhXDGD4KHUVZCbU4ChDoAQhRMAk) - something they probably wouldn't bother to do if it were a common word.

Comment: @stangdon I think Kipling means it to be a faerie word for a human thing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer and photo!!

Comment: And Kipling Journal will be so available from now.  I can try to read some  stories.